# Diagonal video distortion (Ubuntu 20.04.1)

Tags: drivers, graphics, display, video

After installing 20.04.1 persistent diagonal distortions appear in streaming HD video content from multiple sources - Netflix, Amazon, Youtube, Apple Movie Trailers, etc.  A diagonal line forms across the entire screen from top left to bottom right visible for the duration of most videos.  Fast moving scenes with high contrast or heavy CG will also develop large triangles that jut out sideways from this diagonal line that are completely filled with bright, usually white color and devoid of any graphic detail.

I do have super fast vision and experience the 'rainbow effect' with DLP technology, but this distortion is fairly static and very linear as compared to the 'rainbow effect'.  It does disappear on pause though.

I did not enable any third party code after installation and suspect this could be the issue.  I received several prompts about third party software during install, but I can't find guidance on what might need to be enabled/installed.  I haven't received any warning or fault messages from the system since upgrading.

The distortion first appeared yesterday, several days after I upgraded to 20.04.1.  I was able to watch several videos before the issue first appeared, despite the fact that it appears in most video content now.  Reboots, shutdowns, display setting adjustments, and switching to various platforms on Ubuntu does not affect the glitch.  Distortion does not appear when running Windows.

P.S. Running Nvidia Radeon card integral on AMD board with open source Radeon kernel driver

Comment: I take it that this happens in your browser? What browser are you using?

Comment: Yes.  Firefox 82.0 for Ubuntu canonical 1.0.  They must have recently pushed an upgrade, but it also occurs on Ubuntu video apps such as Apple Movie Trailers.  After posting this issue I discovered that the distortions do not appear on Chrome 85.0.4188.121, but the definition is slightly reduced.